# Getting 404 error while fetching data from Mongo DB using Express/Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http-status-code-404

I'm having trouble figuring our this 404 error I'm receiving. This is my first time trying to use Mongo DB and Node.js so forgive me, not used to routing yet. I'm simply trying to make a GET request to localhost:3000/users and render basic text to the page that says "users" so I can test the routes. I have not made any models or schema of any sort yet. I'm getting a message with the following when I get to the page: **Cannot GET /users**.

I believe I have my app.js file set up correctly and the app is connected to Mongo DB.

here's my app.js file - the route is at the bottom:

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

// Instantiate Morgan - this logs requests to the terminal (similar to rails)
const morgan = require('morgan')

// Load config.env file
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

// initialize app with express 
const app = express()


// run Connect DB to connect to your host 
connectDB()

// if environment = development, run request logs
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

// We may deploy to heroku - so we need to set the env variable 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`))


// Routes
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'))
```

And here is my users.js file in my routes folder:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// Routes 
// @route GET /users -> gets all users in the database

router.get('/users', (req, response) => {
    response.send('Users')
})


module.exports = router
```

And for good measure - here's my config.env file. I'm hosting on an AWS server via Mongo DB.

```
PORT = 3000 
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://Ricky:<redacted>@readr.s99uq.mongodb.net/readr?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Any ideas on where I could be going wrong here? I believe I have set the route up properly but may have messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `localhost:3000/users/users` because `/users` points to all routes in your users.js file and in that u have `/users` so it is nested. so if u want result in `localhost:3000/users` in your users.js file change route to `/` instead of `/users`

PS/ Also if thats your real username and password in config file remove that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm and good to know for the rest of my set up. I redacted the password in the config - good looking out.